# How to set a nested routing

Tags: angular, routes

I'm calling an API and I get nested pages.
I can't seem to understand how to create routing.

For pages I understand you can do:

```
   {
      path: ':id',
   }
```

How do you route pages  when the pages are nested and I don't know what page will be nested under what page? All I care that the page gets rendered.

```
   {
      path: 'id/:id',
   }
```

for example:

```
{ id: 1, url: 'food/pizas'}
{ id: 2, url: 'ux/size-shape'}
{ id: 3, url: 'book/house-of-card'}
{ id: 3, url: 'something/other-page'}
```

Comment: what you are asking is unclear, could you add example of what API returns to you and example of "dynamic" route you want you app to handle ?

Comment: @PierreMallet  Updated, it was about nested pages.

Comment: I just saw the "loadChildren" => are you trying to load different lazy modules depending on the id in url ?

Comment: @PierreMallet same module.

Comment: I removed the confusion. I  am talking about when u don't know the category name , or what page will be listed under what page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create you route this way  :

```
{
      path: '/prefix/:category/:id',
      loadChildren: './page/page.module#PageModule',
      canActivate: [
            fromGuards.PrivatePagesGuard,
      ],
      resolve: {
         content: MyDynamicResolver
      }
   }
```

then in your resolver you will have access to category and id params, and thus you can use a service to fetch the resource.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDynamicResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<PageCMS> {
        const category = route.paramMap.get('category');
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');

        return <fetch your content from http or service here>;
    }
}
```

And you will be able to access it in the component through the data of the ActivatedRoute

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.content = this.route.snapshot.data['content'];
}
```

the "/prefix" can be anything and its only purpose is to avaid to create too generic route who could match any url.

Comment: amazing, so I solved 1 think , on how to target nested pages, but what about if my pages are not based on numerical ID but on normal pretty link for example about-me, portfolio, do I find a match for  that? You know how wordpress CMS links up www.domain.com/id=1 to www.domain.com/home , but it renders /home ?

Comment: in the route :category and :id can be anything. If you go /prefix/auto/1 or /prefix/auto/bmw, you well have "auto" in category param and "1" or "bmw" in id param . All params will be strings

Comment: I more about for example in the HTML the link is [routerLink]="[ item.object_cat + item.object_slug]". When it renders it would be      [routerLink]="['whatever/1']". When user clicks on the click , I have a clear ID that I can request from the DB , but I direct the user to domain.com/whatever/bmw because I return from the api that ID 1 is Bwm  page slug

Comment: it's a different problem. I think you will have trouble with doing that cause if the user refreshes his browser, he will lose the id, and you will not be able to render the page. I think your finals URLS should be like /whatever/bmw-1 and in the resolver use a regexp to extract the id then fetch the data from DB. If only the id is in the param then navigate with the router to the "good" URL /whatever/<slug>-<id>